# What happens if the Percent of Apex Used reached 100%?

Tags: apex, governorlimits, limits

I have an org which has

Percent of Apex Used: 89.64%

Just curious to know what happens if we reach 100% of apex code.

Does the salesforce allow the to write code more than that?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You will receive an error message when trying to save files of

> Error: The total size of apex code in this application after removing comments exceeds the maximum character size of 3,000,000

and the files will not submit to the server. You can contact your account executive and may be able to open a discussion to add to this limit if it is deemed appropriate.

Just for you I did this in my Dev org to screenshot the message in action:

[image: Error Message]

It should be noted also that if any individual Apex Class exceeds the 1,000,000 character limit you will get a message like this:

[image: Class limit]

Comment: Salesforce can increase this but will likely do so conditionally and even investigate your code. I believe one of the conditions is that all your test code is in separate classes.

Comment: Wrote all of the test cases individually in a new file for every class in apex

Comment: Who on earth just down-voted this answer??!